# Running tomcat on the docker will not access from broswer

Tags: docker, tomcat

I installed a docker on ubuntu-16.04.

and write this code.

```
docker run -it -d --name tomcat-test -p 8888:8080 tomcat:8.0
```

1. docker ps -> Confirm that it is operating normally
2. on ubuntu shell -> curl http://localhost:8888 -> ok
3. on broswer -> localhost:8888 or 127.0.0.1:8888 or 172.17.0.2:8888 (docker0 ip) -> no..

what's wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the meaning of "no"?

Comment: @Henry error message 'Connection refused from localhost'

Comment: The browser is running on the same machine as docker?

Comment: @Henry The docker runs on Ubuntu on a virtual machine, the browser runs on the host computer (window 10)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/433988/how-to-find-the-ip-address-of-a-vm-running-on-vmware-or-other-methods-of-using

Comment: find vm ip and then open 8888 port with vm ip

Comment: localhost on your windows refers to the windows machine. While tomcat is listening on the Ubuntu VM.

Comment: @Adiii vm ip? Do you speak vm ip(10.0.2.x) instead of docker ip?

Comment: yes check slack answer how to find VM ip so tomcat listening with vm ip not with host machine

Comment: @Henry Then you have to use vm ip like Adiii say?

Comment: @Adiii i try it.

Comment: you got any response in browser?

Comment: one thing more... why not alpine...

Comment: docker run -it --name tomcat-test -p 8888:8080 tomcat:alpine

Comment: i test it localy its work fine. run  docker inspect tomcat-test | grep Gateway

Comment: @Adiii no response broswer..;
alpine ..? i don't know this word.

Comment: @Adiii docker inspect tomcat-test | grep Gateway => 172.17.0.1

Comment: alpine is light weihgt contianer of tomcat size 70mb...tried that ip 172.17.0.1

Comment: @Adiii 172.17.0.1 also no response. and docker inspect tomcat-test | grep IPAddress => 172.17.0.2 also no response..

Comment: what is your vm ip

Comment: @mark3 The IP address of the docker container is irrelevant. You need to use the IP address of the Ubuntu VM. Seems it is 10.0.2.x

Comment: @Adiii vm ip is 10.0.2.0/24 , ubuntu ip is 10.0.2.15, docker ip is 172.17.0.1

Comment: @Henry hmm...10.0.2.15 or 10.0.2.1 no response..

Comment: Why are there two different address for VM and ubuntu? I thought this is the same machine. You have to tell us your exact setup or we cannot help.

Comment: @Henry i wish here is also react to post like fb ;)

Comment: @Henry virtualbox settings NAT network, CIDR is 10.0.2.0/24
and ubuntu 16.04 ip is automatically setting - 10.0.2.15
on ubuntu, typing the 'ifconfig' - docker0 ip is 172.17.0.1/16

Comment: i solved it. 
changed the port forwarding of vm from 8888 8080 to 8888 8888.

Comment: good keep it up